# Поиск по алфавиту

Tags: php

Необходимо сделать поиск по алфавиту, погуглил не нашёл ничего толкового, решил сам с нуля написать для CI. И возник вопрос, можно ли проверить присутствует ли значение в массиве без зависимости от регистра. Функция in_array() к сожалению или счастью зависит от регистра, может есть другие способы, только без написания отдельных функций?!

И ещё очень полезными будут советы по алгоритмам написания поиска по алфавиту. Может кто разрабатывал уже, поделится опытом?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

```
$keys = array_change_key_case(array_flip($haystack));
if (isset($keys[strtolower($needle)])) {
    // ...
}
```

Но лучше так не делать :)